# Updated google anaytics binding?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm having a hard time using the newest google analytics piece with the MonoTouch bindings that Miguel has here: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/monotouch-libs/tree/master/GoogleAnalytics

I'm guessing that the interface has changed a bit in ways that are incompatible, but I'm not sure how to diagnose.  At run time, I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at GoogleAnalytics.GANTracker.get_SharedTracker () [0x00000] in :0

It appears that only two methods were added, so I attempted to add these to "api.cs" - but got a series of compiler errors that didn't seem to tie into the situation.

```
    [Export ("setCustomVariableAtIndex:index:name:value:scope:error"),Internal]
    bool _SetCustomVariableAtIndex(int index, string name, string value, int scope, IntPtr nsErrorPtr);                       

    [Export ("setCustomVariableAtIndex:index:name:value:error"),Internal]
    bool _SetCustomVariableAtIndex(int index, string name, string value, IntPtr nsErrorPtr);
```

Has anyone else overcome this, and is successfully using the NoThumb version of google analytics with MonoTouch ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I got it to work eventually.

I had to use the [btouch](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types) tool, on the latest version of [Google Analytics for iOS](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/download.html).  This recreated the GANTracker.dll.

I also added this to my project file under iPhone Build->Additional mtouch Args:

```
-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/Google -lGoogleAnalytics -lsqlite3.0 -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Google/libGoogleAnalytics.a"
```

I have a Google subfolder in my project with these files:

- GANTracker.dll
- GANTracker.h
- libGoogleAnalytics.a

Sorry, I don't have more specific instructions on btouch, it's been a while.

Comment: You shouldn't use -ObjC, its broken, use -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Google/libGoogleAnalytics.a instead.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this.  I got my project to compile with the above arguments to mtouch.